# Generate list of string from list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects. I am interested in isolating one property of each object, a string value, into a list of strings. How can I create a list of strings using this field only, preferably using Linq and not *manually* looping?

```
class MyObj
{
  int ID {get;set;}
  int AnotherID (get;set;}
  string IneedThis {get;set;}
}

List<MyObj> sampleList = somehow_this_is_populated();
List<string> ls = how do I get this list with values equal to "sampleList.IneedThis"
```

Comment: `sampleList.Select(o => o.IneedThis).ToList();`

Comment: Why the downvote?  So OP did not know LINQ.  It is a well stated question.  LINQ Select is how you create suff.  +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) your property and create a List like:

```
List<string> ls = sampleList.Select(item => item.IneedThis).ToList();
```

Make sure your include `using System.Linq;`

You can also achieve the same with a `foreach` loop like:

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
foreach (MyObj myObj in sampleList)
{
    ls.Add(myObj.IneedThis);
}
```

**Make sure** that your properties in the class are `public`. In your current class then don't have a access modifier and will be considered `private`. Define them like:

```
public string IneedThis { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ.

```
List<string> ls = sampleList.Select(obj => obj.IneedThis).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
List<string> ls = sampleList.Select(x=>x.IneedThis).ToList();
```